# Add button to update Google Spreadsheet. Increment cell and update another cell with current date

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

We have spreadsheet that has a list of members at our gym facility. What we would like to incorporate is a way that a coach could walk around with an iPad and click a button that would "check-in" our members. Usually the number of members present is small - maybe 20-30 members per class. But, we want a way to try to have coach accountability so if someone doesn't show up for 3 weeks, we can reach out in an email to inquire where they have been.

I've created a test spreadsheet that should be editable. I need some help with recommendations or writing a script that would perform the following:

What I would like is a button in the far left "check-in" column next to every member name that our coaches could click when they are present. What that would do would add +1 to the "total check-ins" column and also update the "last time checked-in" column with the current date/time stamp.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnGxNda7E77DdHZldlhQY2hZZlNJamZ6VTZ0WUhqZXc&usp=sharing

I'm brand new to scripting in Google Docs, so thanks in advance for any expertise that is offered! MUCH appreciated!

Comment: A better approach would probably be to build a small UI with a simple listBox containing your members and a button. It would also read and write to your spreadsheet. This would certainly be more useable on a tablet or a phone than a google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvmOEVr803HMdDE5MmZXMlQ1cnpzQ21wYkNNZ19ENXc#gid=0

Script UI (Open this url from any device like Serge said.)
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxfqII2qhtctJTO1nVyLOBZJ4KxElVh8I3fTCFUR1o5R1uOUcA/exec

Code:

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AvmOEVr803HMdDE5MmZXMlQ1cnpzQ21wYkNNZ19ENXc');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('members');
  var members = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(members)


  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Gym Check In');
  var grid = app.createFlexTable().setId('grid');
  app.add(grid);

  var row = 0;
  var column = 0;

  for (var m in members) {    

    grid.setWidget(row, 0, app.createLabel(members[m]));
    grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createButton('Check In').setId(row+2).addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('checkIn').addCallbackElement(grid)).addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)));
    row++;
  }
  return app;
}

function checkIn(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AvmOEVr803HMdDE5MmZXMlQ1cnpzQ21wYkNNZ19ENXc');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('members');

  var button = e.parameter.source;

  sheet.getRange(button, 2).setValue(new Date());  
}
```

Comment: Good job :) I had rather imagine a dropdown list and a single button but this is simpler to use as long as you don't have to many members to show...(maybe put the whole panel in a scrollPanel ?)